# Inequality $e^x-1+e^x(1-\cos \pi y+\sin \pi y)<1$

Tags: inequality

Find *a ranges* of $x,y\in \mathbb R^+$ in which the following inequality is verified

$$e^x-1+e^x(1-\cos \pi y+\sin \pi y)<1$$

**My approach:**

$$2-\cos \pi y+\sin \pi y<\frac{2}{e^x}\leq 2$$

Then

$$-\cos \pi y+\sin \pi y<0$$

that have solution in $y\in(0,1/4)$. Instead, if we isolate the $x$, we have:

$$x<\ln\left(\frac{2}{2-\cos \pi y+\sin \pi y}\right)$$

and $x< \ln2$ in $y\in(0,1/4)$. Then $(x,y)\in (0,\ln2)\times(0,1/4)$. Is my procedure right? I made ​​a mistake?

Thank you very much

Comment: You have found a region in which the inequality is satisfied, but not all the points where it is satisfied. ie your rectangle is a subset of the actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your inequality is satisfied in the blue region to the left. (You should be able to pull it off the screen to examine it in more detail.) It looks like (0,0), ($ln(2)$,0), (0,1/4) , bound by the axes and the boundary of the curve in that region

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ and $y$ are different variables, look for the maximum value of $1 - \cos \pi y + \sin \pi y$. In any case, this looks unlikely: If the last expression is ever larger than $-1$, you have an exponential multiplying a positive value, selecting $x$ large enough gives larger than 1.

Comment: Excuse me but I was not very clear. If calculating the maximum of $1−\cos\pi y+\sin \pi y$, then I do not get a range of values ​​for $y$ but only one value.